# Location City synonym support?

Tags: 7, location

I would like to allow users to search node location using location city with synonyms.

For example:

- New York
- NY
- NYC
- New York City

etc.

should bring the same search results.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have created the related feature request [here](http://drupal.org/node/1571776).

> If this feature is not yet available in the location module, I could
>   maybe use Views, create the indexed synonyms as taxonomy terms
>   vocabulary and term reference field `Content: Location Synonyms`,
>   modify the view's `Global: combine filters filter` setting `Choose
>   fields to combine for filtering` as `Location: City` and `Content:
>   Location Synonyms`? This would require tagging each node `location
>   synonyms` manually or would require setting up a Rule (using Rules
>   contrib module) that would add these synonyms automatically depending
>   on the `Location: City` selected. The standard Drupal search would
>   index these tags.
>
> It would be better to have it either inside the Location module or as
>   an additional contributed helper module.

There is also a contributed module [Location Taxonomize](http://drupal.org/project/location_taxonomize) that might help in achieving this.